# Parse Friend Request Code Won't Work

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I have written some code so one user can send another user a friend request, and this can be accepted or denied.

When you view their profile and press the 'Send friend request' button, this is executed:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:self.userID];
PFUser *selectedUser = (PFUser *)[query getFirstObject];

PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
//request them
PFObject *friendRequest = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"_User"];
friendRequest[@"from"] = currentUser;
//selected user is the user at the cell that was selected
friendRequest[@"to"] = selectedUser;
// set the initial status to pending
friendRequest[@"status"] = @"pending";
[friendRequest saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Yay" message:@"Friend request sent" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
}];
```

But I am getting this error: `[Error]: Caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException" with reason "User cannot be saved unless they are already signed up. Call signUp first."`

The thing is that both user's have already obviously signed up.. I'm pretty confused. Cheers.

Comment: Your error may be because you are trying to treat a `PFUser` as a `PFObject` when you create `friendRequest`. Instead you should do a query on the `_User` class and then select the correct user by searching for specific criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You need to signup (This will also save the user) the user by doing the following:

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
            print("signup");
}
```

You Don't need `user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock`